using 2 cables with 1 port
i want to be able to use 2 usb male cables to a single usb female port to put into a 3d print, is this possable? i havent tried anything yet

What is that 3d "object" shown in your question? What is its relation to the question?

they make naive charge-only "Y" splitters, and USB hubs do that, is that what you're looking for?

@dandavis yes that could work if they come in usb a male, usb c female and 2 differant lenths, i want to route (one for tablet inside arm/tablet holder), @
StarCat this is going to be a tablet/phone holder that mounts on back of a corsair keyboard with a slideout phone holder (on right side)

well you can get small passive splitters (not up to the official USB spec, but handy nonetheless), in the shape of A-male to 2+A female, then use super-common USB A-C cables of different lengths.

It is not possible in any way. It is unclear why you even want to do that. There may be another solution if what you want to achieve is known.

I'm not sure WHAT OP is proposing to do, which is a prerequisite for discussing WHY and whether it is possible.  Perhaps meaning something along the lines of https://www.amazon.com/HIGHROCK-Enhancer-Female-Charge-Extension/dp/B00NIGO4NM which certainly has some limitations but (if it includes the appropriate diodes) is possible and somewhat useful.

@BenVoigt OP wants to plug two male cables into a single female port. If a hub does not do it then that cable (which is completely non-compliant with USB specs and allows damage) won't either.
